# Prioritize left text over right text in react native row

Tags: reactjs, react-native

### Desired Layout

In the below text, title is always the left content and label is always the right content:

- If the title and label are short enough they should hug the left and right respectively, occupying only the space that they need
- If the title is very long it should occupy as much space as possible but always leave at least 100px for the label if there is one
- If the label is very long it should occupy as much space as possible provided it does not truncate the title

[image]

I've tried the following but it doesn't work in all cases:

```
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text style={{ flexShrink: 1 }} numberOfLines={1}>
            {leftText}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ flexShrink: 1 }} numberOfLines={1}>
            {rightText}
          </Text>
        </View>
```

Comment: Could you better explain when a 'right text' should trim? Is it based on amount of chars, min width, whatever else? What does 'all cases' mean? There is no context given in your question.

Comment: Added more context does that make sense?